# Run MySQL Query on API startup

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I have a java REST API, and I am trying to write queries in the database console (I am using Intelli J). My goal is that every time I start the API, it will execute the queries so that I don't constantly have to populate the database myself upon startup.

[my SQL Query in Intelli J](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7ZUA.png)

Comment: You can use a lib like Flyway or Liquibase.

Comment: What's *forcing* you to run a script at all?

Comment: @g00se nothing is forcing me, it’s just since I use two computers (one at home and one whenever I’m away from home) it would be nice to be able to work with the same data.

Comment: Well you can - use the same database ;) But be careful how you configure for remote access. Normally it's not an issue as DBs are used with webapps (safer)

Comment: @g00se how would that look like? I’m still fairly new to all this, I thought docker would help me with that until I read up on what Docker does.

Comment: I can't advise on Docker I'm afraid. But I really don't want to encourage using direct remote access as it causes vulnerability. Consider programming your game app as a webapp